# Calculation of displacement of smaller piston in Hydraulic Jack

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

[image]

In the above hydraulic jack, $L$ is length of pump handle and $x$ is the distance from the pivot to the piston. In each downstroke of the pump, handle moves a vertical distance $h$. I'm more specific on how the pivot plays role on lifting the car along with Pascal's Principle and how the displacement of smaller piston after each downstroke can be calculated as there is no direct apply of force to the piston like in simpler model?

Comment: Hint: displacement volume is conserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the principle of moments (sum of torques equals zero) around $O$

$$F_h L = F_i x$$

Also the pressure is equal throughout the system, so the total force lifting the car is magnified again

$$F_0 = F_i \times \frac{A_{big}}{A_{small}}$$

where the areas are for the big and small piston.

Comment: While calculating displacement of smaller piston, can it be done like this:$$\frac{W}{h}.L=\frac{W}{d}.x$$Since the work done by $F_h$ and $F_i$ are equal. Displacement of smaller piston is given by, $$d=h\frac{x}{L}$$.

Comment: @Bkas Yes, that seems right